# How to find and click on HTML image element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new with Selenium and struggle with this one for few hours. 
I have an HTML page that contains icon and stream view (both images), the browser view is on 100% and I would like to modify it and make it smaller,
it can be done by changing browser zoom, modifying CSS property or clicking on the image.

My code starts with open browser and waits till all elements load:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://' + user +':'+password+'@'+camera_address)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(15) # seconds
```

I tried to do so via zoom:

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='0.4'")
```

Didn't worked.
Tried to do it via Selenium -- find element and change CSS:

```
myDynamicElement = driver.find_elements_by_id("stream")
```

or find the image and click it with:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="../pics/button_downsize_27x27px.gif"]').click()
```

or

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@img]').click()
```

or

```
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img').click()
```

The HTML page looks like this:

```
<a href="JavaScript:zoom(8)" target="_self"><img src="/pics/button_downsize_27x27px.gif" width="27" height="27" border="0" title="Scale down to 800 px width" alt="Scale down to 800 px width"></a>

<td colspan="3" align="center"><img id="stream" src="/mjpg/video.mjpg" width="2560" height="1920" border="0" alt="If no image is displayed, there might be too many viewers, or the browser configuration may have to be changed. See help for detailed instructions on how to do this."><br></td>
```

Tried with @title and @alt and even contain but nothing works.

What am I doing wrong?!?! How to find and click on this image (/pics/button_downsize_27x27px.gif)?

Comment: Please paste the html DOM of your website.

Comment: it's too long, what exactly you would like to see?

Comment: Please check the answer and use it in python and let me know your feedback

Comment: Why do you want to `modify it and make it smaller`? Any particular usecase?

Comment: Please update your question to give the xpath or css selector you tried, so that we can look into they are correct or not.  (You can simply to try them in DevTool, no need to execute script again and again)

Comment: @TzahiKadosh, did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

To click on your desired image -- please use the reference code mentioned here.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy((By.cssSelector("a"))));

List<WebElement> elem = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    for(WebElement el : elem){
        String element = el.getAttribute("src");
        if(element.contains("/pics/button_downsize_27x27px.gif")){
            el.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

It is in Java, you can implement it in Python.

Comment: thank you, tried it, nothing happened

    elem = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    
    for e in elem:
        element = e.getAttribute("src");
        if(element.contains("/pics/button_downsize_27x27px.gif")):
            print element
            e.click()
            break

Comment: element is visible on screen?

Comment: sure, yet, i tried to print the list and it's empty, although it pass without exceptions

Comment: i think ur element is not on the screen viwe mode. First get back the element into the screens center point

Comment: for view the element to center use the code. String scrollElementIntoMiddle = "var viewPortHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);"
                + "var elementTop = arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;"
                + "window.scrollBy(0, elementTop-(viewPortHeight/2));";
  
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(scrollElementIntoMiddle, ele);
  //((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele);
  try {
   Thread.sleep(500);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
  }

Comment: @TzahiKadosh did you try with my latest answer and code in the comment box ?? please let me know your result

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, finally, I did a little workaround since I saw that in chrome there is a little bug and via Firefox, I cannot find the element. 
So I retrieve again the URL after all elements loaded and modify it so the JavaScript function will be triggered:

```
myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'indexMain')))
driver.get(driver.current_url+'&size=8')
```

Thank you all for trying, this one was a challenge since the element have no id/name/class/css and the browser could not find the XPath.